# how to use first_value with reset

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, window-functions

```
WITH t AS
(
    SELECT
        *
    FROM
        (VALUES ('2021-10-09 23:58:34.000', '2021-10-10 00:00:00.000', 'task_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:00:01.000', '2021-10-10 00:00:05.000', 'task_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:00:06.000', '2021-10-10 00:00:25.000',  'task_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:00:26.000', '2021-10-10 00:00:45.000', 'task_not_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:00:46.000', '2021-10-10 00:01:00.000', 'task_not_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:01:01.000', '2021-10-10 00:01:10.000', 'task_completed', '00001'),
                ('2021-10-10 00:01:11.000', '2021-10-10 00:01:15.000', 'task_completed', '00001')) AS t(start_time, end_time, task_state, person_id)
    ORDER BY 
        1
)
SELECT * 
FROM t
```

I am trying to obtain an aggregated result that appears like this:

| start_time | end_time | task_state |
| --- | --- | --- |
| '2021-10-09 23:58:34.000 | 2021-10-10 00:00:25.000' | task_completed |
| '2021-10-10 00:00:26.000 | 2021-10-10 00:01:00.000' | task_not_completed |
| '2021-10-10 00:01:01.000 | 2021-10-10 00:01:15.000' | task_completed |

I have tried using the first_value function  but it just seems to give the value '2021-10-09 23:58:34.000' for all the task_state.

Not sure what I am doing wrong. Here is what I tried:

```
SELECT
    start_time,  
    FIRST_VALUE(start_time) OVER (ORDER BY start_time) AS end_time, 
    MIN(task_state) OVER (ORDER BY start_time) AS state
FROM
    t
```

looking for help for this

Comment: tag your database

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Thanks eshirvana for the response. it looks close to what i want with a few more tweaks. i'm basically trying to get the interval range for when the user started the task, ended the task and started it again. I want to have it in the format just the way i showed the table above. I hope this clarifies my problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its a `gaps & island` problem:

```
SELECT person_id, task_state, MIN(start_time) start_time, MAX(end_time) end_time  
from (
   SELECT * 
       , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.person_id ORDER BY start_time)
       - ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY t.person_id, t.task_state ORDER BY start_time) AS taskgroups
   FROM t
) tt GROUP BY taskgroups, person_id, task_state
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_13&fiddle=3f94a0a877c646f8cbc3589c25668a53)*

Comment: Thanks alot eshirvana!!! this actually solved my problem. I have never heard about the gap and island problem till now.

Comment: @emma_floyd you are welcome, please accept upvote if this answered your question